# Configure file-loader options with Webpack 5 for Next.js

Tags: webpack, next.js

I'm trying to upgrade Nextjs app from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5.
Currently I use `file-loader`  with options in  next.config.js:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|pdf|webm|txt)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              context: '',
              outputPath: 'static',
              publicPath: '_next/static',
              name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
            }
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

According to [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instruction I should change `file-loader` into `type: 'asset/resource'`. I wonder how I can satisfy `options` used in `file-loader`. How can I set public and filesystem path and filename as well?

I have tried to use `output` and `generator.filename` configuration but completely I have no idea where I should put public and filesystem path for Next.js :

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
     filename: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|pdf|webm|txt)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '_next/static/[path][name].[hash].[ext]'
        }
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

### Answer

This works for me.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push(      {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|pdf|webm)$/,
      type: 'asset',
      generator: {
        filename: 'static/chunks/[path][name].[hash][ext]'
      },
    });

      return config;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is the correct configuration of Asset Module in Webpack 5:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|pdf|webm|txt)$/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'static/chunks/[path][name].[hash][ext]'
            },
        });

        return config;
    }
};
```

Be careful not to put a period between `[hash]` and `[ext]`.

Comment: This is not doing anything on the next version 12.0.7, is it working for anyone else?

Comment: @soumitra: Remove the `gnerator.filename` property.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you override webpack configuration correctly? I would expect `next.config.js` changes instead of `webpack.config.js`.

Here you have an article about customizing different part of webpack config in next.js:
https://dev.to/marcinwosinek/how-to-add-resolve-fallback-to-webpack-5-in-nextjs-10-i6j